# Python logging, set basicConfig only if not already set

Tags: python-3.x, python-logging

I am trying to develop an app which has a single entry point, but multiple testing end points. Accordingly, if I set the basicConfig of the logger at the main entry point it may be missed at the time of testing. I thought it is a good idea to have an if clause to check if the basicConfig is set or not and set it if it isn't. But I'm having difficulty finding a way to do so. Is there a way to check if the basicConfig is set or not?

Comment: What do you mean by "multiple testing end points", exactly ?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I mean I have several modules and each can be tested separate from the other ones.

Comment: then - if you do want to have logging enabled during testing (I assume you're talking about unit testing) - just configure the logging in your testrunner. As a generale rule: library code (modules) should NOT configure logging - it's the entry point responsability, whatever the entry point is (your main script, your testrunner, your python shell etc...), the reason being that only the entry point has a chance to know how logging should be configured.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers The testing is not a unit test. It is simply an `if __name__ == "__main__":` in the modules so I can run them independently. In these cases the modules themselves become the entry points at the time of testing. I still shouldn't place the bascConfig in them?

Comment: Ok then they do technically become app entry points, and you can safely configure your logging in this "main" block since it won't be executed when just importing them as modules.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers You have a point! Why didn't I think of that myself! Thanks!

Comment: voting to reopen this question - now we have the details, I think the answer might be of general interest.